# Vue hydration of pre-rendered html: How to mark as static in order to avoid mismatches

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, vue-cli-3, static-site-generation

I have an SPA, built with vue-cli 3.
Some views will be served pre-rendered (SSG) using the npm package [prerender-spa-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prerender-spa-plugin); its option `postProcess` is used to add `data-server-rendered` to the element the vue app will mount to.

During pre-rendering (via Puppeteer renderer) some elements will receive a style attribute with  a value from an async process (need to request some color information of an image from cdn).

The problem:
When the vue app is trying to hydrate the static pre-rendered html there will be a mismatch (between virtual DOM and the pre-rendered markup): During hydration the style attribute hasn't been set yet.
Is there a way to "tell" Vue to accept this mismatch and take the style attribute and its value as static and just ignore it?

I know we could inject the style attribute's value into the pre-rendered html, but this is no option for us for several reasons (we don't have the possibility to do this dynamically).